# Complex Find and Replace in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have hundreds of files that contain something like the following and I want to get rid of that entire chunk.

```
   <texttool id="468" rect="55,306,319,23">
      <toolstroke />
      <toolcolor />
      <font style="2" size="18" />
      <Text>(Be sure to state the page/problem number.)</Text>
    </texttool>
```

The problem is that they all have different `id=XXX` parts... everything else is the same though.

Is there a way to do a mass find and replace to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following Regex that will search through your entire file and remove all  `<texttool>` blocks along with the content inside them:

```
(<texttool(?:.|\n)*?<\/texttool>)
```

**Before**

```
 text before<texttool id="468" rect="55,306,319,23">
      <toolstroke />
      <toolcolor />
      <font style="2" size="18" />
      <Text>(Be sure to state the page/problem number.)</Text>
    </texttool> text after

<texttool id="468" rect="55,306,319,23">
      <toolstroke />
      <toolcolor />
      <font style="2" size="18" />
      <Text>(Be sure to state the page/problem number.)</Text>
    </texttool>
```

**After**

```
 text before text after
```

You can try it out for yourself in this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/DB6fdi/1)

#### Update 1

As requested the following Regex will only remove those `<texttool>` that contain the following property - `rect="55,306,319,23"`:

```
(<texttool.*rect=\"55\,306\,319\,23\"(?:.|\n)*?<\/texttool>)
```

Here is the updated Regex [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/n8L4Hl/1).

*Note that it will only match those blocks that contain that specific string and match its literals character for character.*

#### Update 2

The Regex I provided did not work properly in Notepad++ because it uses a custom PCRE based regex system. Here is a tested and verified pattern that works for me:

```
<\btexttool.*\brect\=\"55\,306\,319\,23\"([\s\S]*?)<\/\btexttool>
```

It's **very important** to disable `. matches newline` option in Notepad++ search window otherwise the pattern will not work, because the provided pattern is not compatible with it.

Comment: There are a bunch of other `<texttool>` tags that I need to keep though.  It's only the one of the kind I showed that needs to go.  Can something be done based on the fact that `rect="55,306,319,23"` will always be in the one I want to get rid of?

Comment: @gtilflm I've updated my answer to match that criteria. Read the note at the end and if you need something more inclusive please provide more information and I will see what I can do.

Comment: Somehow it's grabbing a bunch more `<texttool>` tags, as well as other tags.  The other ones don't have the `rect="55,306,319,23"` property.  No idea why this is happening.

Comment: Could you upload the content of the text file to PasteBin or somewhere similar and then post a link here so I can take a look?

Comment: @gtilflm No problem. It's odd that Npp is not matching the Regex correctly. It works fine on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cag3ga/1).

Comment: @gtilflm I made a second update to the answer in which I included a new regex patten that should work for `Notepad++`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: it's better but it's leaving a `>` and it also caught this `<texttool id="951" rect="55,614,83,23">...` when it shouldn't have.

Comment: @gtilflm So sorry about that, it's getting pretty late here so I must be getting a bit tired. I've made a silent edit to the answer, check regex under update 2 again.

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<texttool\b[^>]*?\brect="55,306,319,23"(?:(?!<texttool\b).)*</texttool>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<texttool\b             # open tag
[^>]*?                  # 0 or more any character that is not >, not greedy
\brect="55,306,319,23"  # literally
                    # Tempered greedy token
(?:                     # start non capture group
 (?!<texttool\b)        # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't same tag
 .                      # any character
)*                      # end group, may appear 0 or more times
</texttool>             # end tag
```

**Given:**

```
  <grouptool id="881" rect="20,576,456,141">
    <imagetool id="882" rect="349.15240478515625,581.5066528320312,111.22747039794922,132.8365936279297">
      <toolstroke WIDTH="1.0" CAP="2" JOIN="2" MITER="0.0" />
      <bordercolor />
      <image name="head-set-md.png" type="CLIPART" size="20419" w="252" h="300" CRC="3224584205" />
    </imagetool>
    <texttool id="884" rect="30,584,214,31">
      <toolstroke />
      <toolcolor />
      <font style="3" size="24" />
      <Text>Got Audio Problems?</Text>
    </texttool>
    <texttool id="885" rect="55,306,319,23">
      <toolstroke />
      <toolcolor />
      <font style="2" size="18" />
      <Text>Note: Audio problems can be caused</Text>
    </texttool>
    <imagetool id="886" rect="36.17853927612305,631.7913818359375,262.9012756347656,24.34532356262207">
      <toolstroke WIDTH="1.0" CAP="2" JOIN="2" MITER="0.0" />
      <bordercolor />
      <image name="unknown.png" type="CLIPART" size="1777" w="260" h="24" CRC="2321804736" />
    </imagetool>
    <texttool id="887" rect="55,306,319,23">
      <toolstroke />
      <toolcolor />
      <font style="2" size="18" />
      <Text>by a weak/spotty internet connection.</Text>
    </texttool>
    <rectangletool id="888" rect="249.5330505371093,627.7338256835938,30.33476448059082,31.446043014526367">
      <toolstroke WIDTH="4.0" />
      <toolcolor RGB="52224" />
      <fillcolor RGB="16777215" ALPHA="0" />
    </rectangletool>
  </grouptool>
```

**Result for given example:**

```
  <grouptool id="881" rect="20,576,456,141">
    <imagetool id="882" rect="349.15240478515625,581.5066528320312,111.22747039794922,132.8365936279297">
      <toolstroke WIDTH="1.0" CAP="2" JOIN="2" MITER="0.0" />
      <bordercolor />
      <image name="head-set-md.png" type="CLIPART" size="20419" w="252" h="300" CRC="3224584205" />
    </imagetool>
    <rectangletool id="883" rect="20,576,455.0214538574219,141">
      <toolstroke />
      <toolcolor />
      <fillcolor RGB="16777215" ALPHA="0" />
    </rectangletool>


    <imagetool id="886" rect="36.17853927612305,631.7913818359375,262.9012756347656,24.34532356262207">
      <toolstroke WIDTH="1.0" CAP="2" JOIN="2" MITER="0.0" />
      <bordercolor />
      <image name="unknown.png" type="CLIPART" size="1777" w="260" h="24" CRC="2321804736" />
    </imagetool>

    <rectangletool id="888" rect="249.5330505371093,627.7338256835938,30.33476448059082,31.446043014526367">
      <toolstroke WIDTH="4.0" />
      <toolcolor RGB="52224" />
      <fillcolor RGB="16777215" ALPHA="0" />
    </rectangletool>
  </grouptool>
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]